# How do I access Google AdWords API with Node.js?

Tags: node.js, google-ads-api

Is there a way to use node.js to access and manage a google adwords account?

Answer (score 1):

I'm the author of an unofficial node.js client library for AdWords: https://www.npmjs.com/package/googleads-node-lib.  It is getting closer to a feature complete client library every day.  Pull requests welcome.

Comment: can you library output this table in the article, check link https://crealytics.com/blog/2014/04/29/hourly-click-conversion-data-adwords/

I need to achieve this via javascript.

Comment: @Erik do you have a node script to generate the refresh token?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the library uses standard Javascript (it is built using Google's Closure library). What you might need to do is to write an HttpWebTransport adapter that works for Node.js. http://code.google.com/p/google-api-adwords-js/source/browse/#svn%2Ftrunk%2Fjs%2Fsystem%2Fsrc%2Fgoogle%2Fsystem%2Fnet has a few examples for specific technlogies like Google Gadgets, Chrome extensions, etc. , but there isn't one for Node.js. Also see http://code.google.com/p/google-api-adwords-js/source/browse/trunk/js/adwordsapi/src/config.js for details on how to configure the library to use a particular HttpWebTransport class.

Cheers,
Anash

Comment: Btw, you may want to post any followup questions on the official AdWords API forum, as it is monitored by the current maintainers of that library:

http://code.google.com/apis/adwords/forum.html

Cheers, Anash

Answer (score 0):

There you go: https://www.npmjs.com/package/google-ads-api

Adwords are deprecated for now.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -3):

I don't know much about node.js but if it's using standard JavaScript then you should be able to get somewhere with the new AdWords API JavaScript library: http://code.google.com/p/google-api-adwords-js/