# Google Adwords and Node.js: library or different way to access API?

Tags: node.js, google-ads-api

Is there a node.js library for google adwords? Or what is the current recommended way to access Adwords from node.js?

There's this [question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6475032/node-js-how-to-access-google-adwords-api). I guess this is not up-to-date?

As I can see no js-library [here](https://developers.google.com/adwords/api/docs/clientlibraries), I assume, I should use something else...

Answer (score 1):

There is no official library written in JS or Node.Js.

You can search on https://npmjs.com for a package provided by the community.

[This one](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-adwords) looks to be the most advanced (full features) and up-to-date (last revision was some hours ago). There is no issue opened and npmjs says that it is quite dowloaded often (300/month), so I would go for it.